# Не получается подключить document.getElementById как из внешнего файла, так и из внутренней части HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Не получается подключить document.getElementById как из внешнего файла, так и из внутренней части HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="openMenu()">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>Меню сайта</li>
        <li><a href="/">Главная</a> </li>
        <li><a href="/">Портфолио</a> </li>
        <li><a href="/">Продукты</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Прайс</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    function openMenu() {
        document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toogle('active');
    }
</script>
```

В браузере в качестве ошибок выходят эти строки:

```
<div class="toggle-btn" onclick="openMenu()">
document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toogle('active');
```

**Ожидал, примерно такого результата:**

[image: Клик по трём полоскам]

[image: Закрывающий клик]

[Пытался сделать такую же вещь как в данном видео-уроке](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJAdN9TLqLk&list=LL&index=1)

**Не знаю в чём проблема. Дело не только именно в этом подключении document.getElementById, мне кажется я вообще как-то не так его подключаю. Когда я пробовал делать другие страницы и подключать таким же способом document.getElementById только с другими словами в скобках тоже ничего не работало. Заранее спасибо за ответ**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените `toogle` на `toggle`  и будет всё работать.

И пользуйтесь IDE с подсветкой синтаксиса и автодополнением функций и методов.